# Why does an ostream iomanip not need template parameters when passed to operator<<?

Tags: c++, templates, iostream

In namespace std, of the gnu stdc++ header ostream, this is the definition of std::endl:

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
    inline basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
    endl(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os)
    { return flush(__os.put(__os.widen('\n'))); }
```

Why is it possible to write `std::cout << std::endl;` where `endl` is used without template parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) taking manipulators as function pointer. [Template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Template_argument_deduction) is performed when being passed template like `std::endl`, thus template arguments don't need to be specified explicitly.

> When possible, the compiler will deduce the missing template arguments from the function arguments. This occurs when a function call is attempted and when an address of a function template is taken.
>
> This mechanism makes it possible to use template operators, since
>   there is no syntax to specify template arguments for an operator other
>   than by re-writing it as a function call expression.
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
> int main() 
> {
>     std::cout << "Hello, world" << std::endl;
>     // operator<< is looked up via ADL as std::operator<<,
>     // then deduced to operator<<<char, std::char_traits<char>> both times
>     // std::endl is deduced to &std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>
> }
> ```

Given `std::cout << std::endl;`, the parameter type of the appropriate `operator<<` is `std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>&)`, then the template arguments of [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) would be deduced as `char` and `std::char_traits<char>`.

Comment: as a reference, `basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>` defines this member function:

`basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
      operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))`